# Software to generate dynamic reports with c# and VS

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm currently searching for a report generator software, but the problem is:

I have many clients, and in my software the client chooses the features that he wants to be in the report, so it is hard to have all combinations of features in reports. I'm looking for a software that generates a generic reports, uses a XML or JSON as a data source for the report and can export as PDF and be printed in my software.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Perhaps Power BI embedded: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-embedded/ or Google for something like "c# report engine"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm, what you need is a tool like Zoho Reports, Tableau or similars